# Bitrix вывести список новостей, исключая текущую

Tags: битрикс

Сайт на bitrix. На страницу отдельной новости также выведен список всех новостей. Как исключить из этого списка текущую новость?

Comment: В result_modifier подключаемого компонента  написать код, который вырежет текущую новость.

Comment: Спасибо, выкрутился через стандартный фильтр компонента.

Comment: Для полноты информации. Делать как предложил АК не надо. Это костыль. Представьте вам необходимо выводить 3 новости. Т.е. необходимо будет запрашивать лишнюю. И обеспечивать вывод только необходимого количества. Если список новостей с пагинацией - еще веселей.   Работа через фильтр это не "выкрутился", это правильный метод

Comment: Да, я тоже так считаю. Лишний запрос плюс впоследствии оперирование фантомными элементами списка.

Answer (score 3):

Воспользовался фильтром компонента. Код принял вид:

```
<?
global $arrFilter;
$arrFilter = array("!=ID" => $_REQUEST["ID"]);
?>
```

В настройках компонента соответственно нужно выставить имя фильтра:

```
"FILTER_NAME" => "arrFilter",
```

Answer (score 0):

Использую такой вариант на странице детальной новости, для исключения текущей.

1. Разместить код фильтра перед компонентом список новостей.

   ```
   <?$GLOBALS['arrFilter'] = array("!ID"=> $ElementID);?>
   ```
2. В настройках компонента указать название фильтра arrFilter